# How to access function in click handler function?

Tags: javascript, client, openlayers

I create this class using pure javascript:

```
var SelectFeature = /*@__PURE__*/(function (Select) {
    function SelectFeature() {
        Select.call(this, {
            condition: ol.events.condition.click
        });
    }

    this.on('select', function (e) {
        //some logic
    });

    if (Select) SelectFeature.__proto__ = Select;
    SelectFeature.prototype = Object.create(Select && Select.prototype);
    SelectFeature.prototype.constructor = Select;

    return SelectFeature;
}(ol.interaction.Select));
```

as you can see I pass ol.interaction.Select as a parameter to the class and using Select.call() the method in SelectFeature as a constructor.

Here is a [description](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Select-Select.html) of ol.interaction.Select class.

The ol.interaction.The select class has a member who is called getFeatures(). 
I try to access this method when some DOM element is clicked(this block is inside SelectFeature class):

```
$("#popupFeat-closer").click(function () {
    this.getFeatures();
});
```

The code above is fired when DOM element is clicked but, on this row:

```
this.getFeatures();
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.getFeatures is not a function
```

My question how can I access getFeatures function which is located in click event handler?

Comment: Its a scoping issue. Here: `this.getFeatures()` this is pointing to the jQuery object pointing to element.

Comment: @Rajesh, thanks for the post. Any possible solutions?

Comment: Its difficult to suggest as I have never worked on OL and with the code provided, I don't even see where and how `SelectFeature` is used. If you could share the usage and linking code, it would be easier for us

Comment: you may try arrow function ```$("#popupFeat-closer").click( () => 
    this.getFeatures();
);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it is mention in the comments, you have a context problem. Almost every library or framework has a method to keep the context, in jQuery you can achieve this with `proxy` method. Something like this should work,

```
$("#popupFeat-closer").click($.proxy(function () {
    this.getFeatures();
}), this);
```

I would say that is always good to use the library/framework way of solving these, but the "old" way works too,

```
var self = this;
$("#popupFeat-closer").click(function () {
    self.getFeatures();
});
```

[jQuery Docs - proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Comment: Thanks for the post! Can I achive it with help of pure javascript?

Comment: You mean no jQuery?. The second solution is pure JavaScript, basically you keep the context in the variable `self`. This variable, `self`, is in the scope of the click handler.